# gnome-terminal --geometry not working in centos 8

Tags: centos, gnome3, startup, gnome-terminal, multi-monitor

In order to have a terminal launch on my secondary monitor upon login I used to have a command like the following as a startup application:

`gnome-terminal --geometry 80x24+2120+200 --full-screen --hide-menubar`

However, since upgrading to Centos 8 that no longer seem to work. Terminal launches, but on my primary monitor rather than my secondary. Changing the numbers supplied to geometry seem to have little impact on what place/shape the window ends up in.

How do I instruct gnome to open the terminal on the right monitor?